# Handlebars formatting in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using NetBeans as my IDE for a Ember.js project.  When I create handlebars templates in my app like below the code highlighting doesn't work correctly.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
     <div>
     </div>
</script>
```

Normally, when I'd select the first div, it and its matching end tag would highlight yellow, but this doesn't work.  Since its inside the handlebars script tag both are highlighted red as errors and don't match together.  This makes writing complex templates kinda annoying as it can be difficult to pinpoint syntax errors.

Is there anyway to get NetBeans to highlight inside the handlebars tag as if its regular html?

Comment: Not sure about netbeans but going with Sublime text for ember development is a good option. I have been using it for Ember development for more than a month now and find it very good to use.

Comment: I ended up switch to Sublime Text and am so glad I did. Very much worth it.

Answer (score 2):

One option, until Netbeans implements this [enhancement](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243803), is to add the following script tag in index.html immediately after your reference to jQuery:

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- use following line to change script type to 'text/x-handlebars' -->
<script>jQuery('script[type="text/html"]').attr('type', 'text/x-handlebars');</script>
```

This is a variation of the answer provided by GCoda.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried various non satisfying fixes.

In the end I figured the best solution is simply to change the script's type attribute to `text/html`:

```
<script type="text/html">
     <div>
     </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that will work with Ember.  The type has to be `text/x-handlebars` for it to register the template.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read over the ember.js part. As you noted, this approach only works with manual template compiling. Sorry

Comment: I filed an [enhancement](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243803), which eventually should enable HTML handling inside script tags with the following types: "text/x-handlebars-template", "text/x-handlebars" and also "text/template". Hopefully this feature will be implemented in the near future... I'll post back to this thread then

Comment: Could you please answer your own question so that it's removed from unanswered?

Comment: This is useful, at least it helps me with formatting while editing the template

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. And i just used a some kind of postprocessing, i am using node.js, so i did `res.send(data.replace(/type="text\/html"/g,'type="text/x-handlebars"'));` on my `/` page.

I think you can do something similar in you language, and ofcource this is not a fix, just an ugly trick to make developing more easy. Dont keep it in production.